# DataAdapter.Update(DataSet) не сохраняет данные

Tags: c#, entity-framework, binding, wpf

Есть маленькая табличка DataGrid, привязанная к базе данных через binding.
Если вызываю метод Update(DataSet) в обработчике события CellEditEnding или RowEdinEnding

```
private void CellEditEndingHandler(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    dataSetAdapter.Update(DataSet);
}
```

изменения сохраняются только в предпоследней строке. Изменения, внесенные в последнюю строку, не сохраняются.
Если этот метод вызываю в обработчике клика по кнопке

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     dataSetAdapter.Update(DataSet);
 }
```

все работает.
Кнопка - не удобно. Хочется, чтобы сохранялось автоматически. Почему не работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходя из [этой статьи](http://codefluff.blogspot.de/2010/05/commiting-bound-cell-changes.html), изменения попадают в модель, только когда строка теряет фокус.

Попробуйте вызвать [`CommitEdit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd402940%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
bool inManualCommit = false;
void CellEditEndingHandler(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (inManualCommit) return;
    try
    {
        inManualCommit = true;
        DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)sender;
        grid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
        dataSetAdapter.Update(DataSet);
    }
    finally
    {
        inManualCommit = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @xlmax: сработало?

Comment: Хм, заработало!
Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: @xlmax: Пожалуйста!